# Plugin function inside custom plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

I am trying to use a plugin function ( `wp-bannerize()` ) inside my custom plugin. but when i write:

```
if( function_exists('wp_bannerize') ){
            echo "exist";
        }else{
            echo "not exist";
        }
```

The output is `not exists`

How can i get this function inside my custom plugin?

UPDATE:

Here the code of my plugin:

```
class Infinite_posts{

    public function __construct() { 

        add_action('wp_ajax_is_bannerize', 'load_plugins');
//when plugin receive an AJAX call with 'is_bannerize'parameter load_plugins() is triggered

    }

    public function load_plugins(){
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'show_bannerize' );
//when all plugin are loaded show_bannerize() is triggered
    }

    public function show_bannerize(){
        if( function_exists( 'wp_bannerize' ) ) {
            echo "exist";
        } else {
            echo "not exist";
        }       
    }
}

if( !is_admin() )
    $infinitePosts = new Infinite_posts();
```

here my javascript too:

```
$('.gallerie h2').on('click', function(){
  jQuery.post(
      'http://localhost/~sdibenedetto/d-art/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/infinite-posts/infinite-posts.php', 
      {
          'action': 'is_bannerize',
          'data':   'foobarid'
      }, 
      function(response){
          alert('The server responded: ' + response);
      }
  );

});
```

Is this correct?
How to make the AJAX call and pass the parameter "is_bannerize" to trigger the plugin?
With this javascript i have this error in the alert:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function add_action() in <b>/Users/sdibenedetto/Sites/d-art/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/infinite-posts/infinite-posts.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
```

Pls help.
Thanks

Comment: The answer by @Dero is almost certainly on the right track. Post your code in context. There must be some detail missing.

Comment: @dero @ s_ha_dum here some updates

Comment: There's simply not enough relevant code here to provide context. From the code here, there's no way to know where/how/when this code is *interacting with WordPress*. And without knowing that, there's no way to know why `function_exists()` is returning false.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably making the check too early. Make sure all plugins are loaded before trying to access the methods they provide. You can hook into `plugins_loaded` action to make sure all plugins are loaded before trying to use the functions they define.

```php
class My_Plugin {
    public static function init() {
        if( function_exists( 'wp_bannerize' ) ) {
            echo "exist";
        } else {
            echo "not exist";
        } 
    }
    public function __construct() { ... }
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array ( 'My_Plugin', 'init' ), 10 );
```

Comment: thank you Dero...but even with this i got "not exist"

Comment: @SalvatoreDibenedetto Sorry to hear that. Are you sure you have WP Bannerize plug-in activated? I just tried to create a testing plug-in using my code and it detects the `wp_bannerize` function correctly with the latest version of WP Bannerize plug-in.

Comment: WP Bannerize 3.0.52?

Comment: `plugins_loaded` might still be too soon if this plugin is loaded before WP Bannerize is loaded. Try changing the priority from the default 10 to 20 (which is working for me), or even try a later hook, such as `init`

Comment: @helgatheviking `plugins_loaded` run when *all* plugins are loaded. If it works using an lower priority and not using standard 10, _probably_ is because *target* plugin use same hook to load file containing the function... This is the reason why when in a plugin we need another plugin function  we should use the *proper hook*. And what's the *proper hook* depends on third party plugin... normally `wp_loaded` is a good choice, but there isn't a general rule...

Comment: Good point. I'm not overly familiar with the plugin, but it looks like the main plugin file requires another file where `wp_bannerize()` is defined, so I'm not sure why the default priority didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. You cannot hook object methods like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_is_bannerize', 'load_plugins');
```

You need to hook them like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_is_bannerize', array($this,'load_plugins'));
```

I am puzzled how you get output at all.

Secondly, you are calling the plugin file directly. Don't do that. Loading a file by a direct URL like this-- `http://localhost/~sdibenedetto/d-art/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/infinite-posts/infinite-posts.php`-- will cause the file to load outside of a WordPress context. You will have all kinds of "undefined function" errors and other functionality problems. Your class appears to be trying to use the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) but your Javascript is not. You need to use the API.

Correct those issues and come back if there are still other problems.

Comment: +1 and yes, will be other problems, at least one, `plugins_loaded` run *before* `wp_ajax_*` actions...

Comment: And probably also `wp_ajax_no_priv_*` is needed here...

Comment: @G.M. : :) I thought of that possibility but didn't look it up to be sure, and decided to take this one a few steps at a time :)

Comment: @s_ha_dum how it should be my javacript to use AJAX API? i added below: `$infinitePosts = new Infinite_posts();` this line:
`wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( 'infinite-posts.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));` but nothing changed and no file was added to my page...

Comment: Read the Codex entry carefully, and do some research. All AJAX requests should go through `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`